# HackerRank Python Compile Error Recursion Factorial

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem**

Calculate and print the factorial of a given positive integer. The integer can be as large as `100`.

[Here's a link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/extra-long-factorials)

**My effort**

I have tried solutions on other compilers, they are working fine on other compilers, but on hackerrank its not working saying **compile time error**

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
def fac(n):
    return 1 if (n < 1) else n * fac(n-1)

no = int(raw_input())
print fac(no)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This solution works just fine for **Python 2** - I ran your code on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com) and it passed all the test cases.

So, the compilation error is shown if the code is compiled with **Python 3**.

> no = int(raw_input())
>
> NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

That's true because `raw_input` must be replaced with `input()` in **Python 3**.

If the code with the correction is executed afterwards then there's another issue:

> print fac(no)
>
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Again, just add parentheses around `fac(no)` and then the code compiles and passes all the tests:

So, the full code is below:

```
def fac(n):
    return 1 if (n < 1) else n * fac(n-1)

no = int(input())
print (fac(no))
```